# React - fetch children data on accordion extand

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of objects and each one of them is a Bootstrap's Accordion. In the question I also use Card of Bootstrap.

The outter class contains:

```
render() {
    return <Accordion> {
        this.state.something.map((value, index) => { return <SingleObject key={index} {...value}/>
    } </Accordion>
}
```

Each instance of "SingleObject" is constructed as follow:

```
render() {
    ....
    return <Card>      
        <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey={props.patient_id} style={headerStyle}>
          -- code --
        </Accordion.Toggle>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={props.unique_id}>
          <Card.Body> 
            <SingleObjectInnerView unique_id={props.unique_id}/>
          </Card.Body>            
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
}
```

Now to the question. `SingleObjectInnerView` loads his data from an API using `unique_id` in his `componentDidMount`. My problem is that it fetch the data for all the `SingleObjectInnerView` instances at the same time.

`Accordion` can call a callback when the header is clicked. I want to fetch the children data when the Accordion header is clicked. In my current design, I need to trigger a children method from the parent. I understood that its a bad code small and a better design should exist.

How can I make that the children would only load the data when they are viewed?

Comment: which library are Card, Accordion, and SingleObjectInnerView be called from?

Comment: "Accordion can call a callback when the header is clicked"
I don't understand which `Accordion` you are referring to. Please add a dummy callback in the code. And what do you expect to show after the click but before the data has loaded?

Comment: both of them are bootstrap. edited to specify it